# Sesiones PHP; Inicio de sesión obligatoria para acceder a menú

Tags: php, sesiones

estoy en desarrollo de una pagina web pero me surge la incógnita de como lograr que para poder entrar a mi menú sea necesario loguearse y no solo con teclear la url se pueda acceder

Codigo index.php:

```
<?php session_start();
?>
<html>     
 <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <title>Ingresar al Sistema</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo1.css">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

</head>
<body> 
 <div>
  <div id=header>

   <img src="images/logocfe.png" width="200" height="100" alt="Logo CFE" />

   <table width="1339" class="barra" height="30" border="0" bgcolor="#336633">
          <td></td>
   </table>
 </div>

    <h1 class="register-title">Bienvenido</h1>

     <center><form name='login' class="register" method='post' action='login.php'>

              <tr>
                 <td><label>Usuario:</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><input type='text'  class="register-input" required name='Usuario' maxlenght='10'></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><label>Clave/RP:</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><input type='password' class="register-input" required name='RPE'></label><br><br></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><center><input type='submit' class="register-button" id='boton' value='Iniciar sesión'></label></center></td>
              </tr> 

            </form></center>
 </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <center>
    <p>&copy; Empresa X <?php echo date("Y");?></p>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Código login.php

```
<html>
 <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <title>Acceso Denegado</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo4.css">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <div id=header>

   <img src="images/logocfe.png" width="200" height="100" alt="Logo CFE" />

    <table width="1339" class="barra" height="30" border="0" bgcolor="#336633">
         <td></td>
   </table>
 </div>

 <div class="menu" id=registro>
   <?php session_start();

     $Usuario=$_POST['Usuario'];
     $RPE=$_POST['RPE'];

     $query = "SELECT idAdmin, Usuario FROM administradores WHERE Usuario='$Usuario' AND    RPE='$RPE'";
     include('libreria.php');
     $result=conectar_bd($query);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

           $_SESSION['idAdmin']=$row[0];
           $_SESSION['Usuario']=$row[1];
             header ("Location: menu.html");

         }
         else
         {
           echo "<center>ERROR: No existe el usuario o la clave es incorrecta. <br><br></center>";
           echo "<center><a href='index.html'>INTENTAR DE NUEVO</a><br></center>";
           }

   ?>

  <center><img src="images/error.png" width="350" height="250" alt="Logo CFE"/></center>
 </div>
 <center>
  <p>&copy; Empresa x<?php echo date("Y");?></p>
 </center>
</body>  
</html>
```

Código menu.html

```
<?php session_start();
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo3.css" type="text/css" media="all">
 <title>Menú Principal</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div id=header>

  <img src="images/logocfe.png" width="200" height="100" alt="Logo CFE" />

  <table width="1339" class="barra" height="30" border="0" bgcolor="#336633">
         <td></td>
  </table>

 </div>

 <div class="menu">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><a class="ie6" href="#url"><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
       <ul class="sub">
         <li><a href="consultas.php"><b>Consultar IP</b><p>Consultar Direcciones IP dentro de la red local</p><i></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="alta.html"><b>Registrar IP</b><p>Registrar una nueva dirección IP</p><i></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="altaadmin.html"><b>Nuevo Administrador</b><p>Registrar a un nuevo administrador</p><i></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="index.php"><b>Salir</b><p>Cerrar sesión actual</p><i></i></a></li>
       </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
  </ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<script>
  window.alert("Identificacion Exitosa");
</script>
<center>
 <p>&copy;EMPRESA X<?php echo date("Y");?></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tendrias q comprobar q cuando cargue la pagina, si esta la sesión iniciada. De lo contrario, redirige al login.

Comment: ¿Como podría hacerlo?

Comment: En el php podrias hacer **if(!(isset($_SESSION["Usuario"]))){ //algo para redirigir al loguin}**

Comment: Esto en mi login.php, cierto?

Comment: Yo lo pondria en el index.php. Tiene q ser en la pagina principal, ya es la q no se podrá acceder si no esta logueado.

Comment: Te recomiendo q mires algun video o leas algun tutorial de como estructurar tu codigo para hacer un manejo de sesiones. Puede q te orienten un poco, o te den algun tip interesante.